# Changing NIC or Vendor

Tags: raspbian, networking, hardware, setup, root

I'm currently using the Raspberry Pi for a solution, but I want to hide the fact that it is a RPI doing the work. However, when using Fing or any other network scanner, it recognises the vendor as "Raspberry Pi Foundation", which I want to either hide or replace with my own "vendor" name.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi. Please press the up button to give thanks to an answers. People will write in comments if something is unclear. You can always edit your answer. Please read the site FAQ too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is just 
`ifconfig eth hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

You can also install macchanger:
`sudo apt-get install macchanger`
Features:
* set specific MAC address of a network interface
* set the MAC randomly
* set a MAC of another vendor
* set another MAC of the same vendor
* set a MAC of the same kind (eg: wireless card)
* display a vendor MAC list (today, 6200 items) to choose from
Site : http://www.alobbs.com/macchanger

NB: whichever method you use, you may have tou try while the interface is up, or down, depending on the driver. `ifconfig eth0 up` / `ifconfig eth0 down`

Comment: If you want to remain anonymous, don't forget to install and properly configure a software firewall as well.  That will help mask more than just your hardware vendor.

Comment: Hi,

This works, but then I can't get the IP address of the RPI. It shows as "UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST" but I need the IP, and for it to be on the network so that I can use it.

Any solution? Essentially, changing MAC -> lost IP/connection

Comment: @fypfyp Which of the solutions did you do?  If you did the `ifconfig` one, keep in mind that the MAC address you specify must be [valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)

Comment: @fypfyp it depends on your network. Try `sudo dhclient eth0`

Comment: The site is down now, it seems to be just a blog page...... http://www.alobbs.com/macchanger